# MVC pattern with http servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller

I need to implement a servlet with java and a tomcat server. I also need to use the MVC pattern.

So the model part is clear to me. But how do I seperate view and controler in this case? I thought my `httpServlet` class is my view, but how do I then implement the controller?

Comment: httpServlet  is the Controller and View is you page which is use to display data,like jsp

Comment: Your servlets would be your controller, you understand model and view can be anything jsp, servlet responses, htmls etc.

Comment: @Gospel , do I store the jsp in the model?

Comment: the model is a kind of data,you can think the model is the data that you want to display in you view

Comment: exactly what you need. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Model** is your business data that you deal with. and finally you sent it to client to render in view(JSP)

**View** is your Jsp Pages which controller sends to the client, based on client request.

**Controller** is your Servlet which accept the client request and execute your business logic and select appropriate view(JSP) and return it to client.

see the below Example where `TestServlet` is your **Controller**, `Index.jsp` is you **view**.

```
public class TestServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //business logic that deal with the your Model


        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
               rd.forward(request, response);
        }


}
```

Comment: great, thanks. So I will be creating objects of my model in the controller. And if I understand correct, I will have a couple of controllers... how do I forward these objects to the other controllers? Can I include them in the request/response?

Comment: Exactly you can have separate controller for each actions login,signup...
 
you can put your model object into request parameter `request.setParameter("your model")` or you can set in session depends on the requirements  and there is no need to call one controller withing another controller.

Answer (score 0):

The httpServlet is the controller, The servlet needs to forward request to a JSP(Jsp is termed as view).